# How to bind element attributes: bind-attr or bindAttr?

Tags: ember.js

is the documentation for binding element attributes correct?

[1] and [2] says that you have to use e.g. {{bind-attr src=logoUrl}}. is it possible, that it is bindAttr and not bind-attr?

[1] http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/
[2] http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_bind-attr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since release of  ember-1-0-rc8 http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html, 
under *Other Improvements*

> Alias linkTo to link-to and bindAttr to bind-attr for consistency with
>   HTML naming. Old names remain but are soft-deprecated

so it depends on the ember.js version in use and, if possible, better to use bind-attr